# How do i resolve this Mongo Server Selection Error

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, backend

Am quiet new to backend and database. I have a solution currently using mongodb. It was working fine till yesterday when i starting having the connect **ETIMEDOUT 13.37.254.237:27017** error. Nothing was changed in the URI path or tampered with. It just started and i have not been able to sort it out.

is there any help available please?

I have created another cluster and its working well. But my initial cluster that has datas which are live from clients is not connecting still.

My connection code
I have used these connections code but it has not worked. It was connecting fine all through yesterday but today without tampering with the code, couldn't connect to my mongodb

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

[my mongoose connection and the timedout error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fdjD.png)

Comment: which version mongoose you re using ?

Comment: thanks. The connection has been restored on its own...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you connect to Mongodb using IPs that keep updating from your system causes this kind of issues.

also this can be due to your network connection. So i will advice you to:

1. To allow connection from any IP address(but must ensure your URI is not made known to the public to avoid attack/ access from unwanted users.)

2.Check your network status(data)
3.  Run the mongo URI on your atlas